# can not save field permissions in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-permissions

I have added new fields to such content type in drupal 6, then go to permission page to enable these fields to specific role but I can not save the new permission.

anybody can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: simply, in admin/user/permissions when click "Save permission" can anything save !!!!

Comment: This is weird! Try to run cron and have a look at the `status report` page.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for reply, when run cron manually I got this wwarning in status report warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/jeel_ayman/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module on line 1242. and user warning: Table 'jeel_amc.cache_shorten' doesn't exist query: DELETE FROM cache_shorten WHERE expire != 0 AND expire < 1352099841 in /var/www/html/jeel_ayman/includes/cache.inc on line 166.

Comment: Try to run `update.php` then run cron.

Comment: Flush the cache, run `update.php` then run cron :)

Comment: man just for one role i can not save the permission and the others are ok, so what is the reason :(. once i run this 'admin/user/permissions/3' and click save permissions nothing happened but once run admin/user/permissions/5 the permissions are saved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19089/discussion-between-ayman-hussein-and-muhammad-reda)

Comment: Try to go to 'admin/user/permissions' (without any role IDs in the URL) and save the permissions.

Comment: Thanks guys I solved it by increase max_input_var variable for PHP